# Google Earth API for 3D street View

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-earth

I want to take a Google Earth 3D View specially Street view in which, User or particular visitor of the App will be able to see the real world to scan real object. Now My question is, If we got Google Earth API with 3D Street view enable, does it will support in iOS Device ? if yes then, where will I get that stuff. Please help me to get this problem solved. I would be more Happy and Thankful to that Developer

Thanks

Comment: What you need is google map api. Yes Unity is supported for mobile apps. (not web) https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/gaming/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if what you are trying to achieve is something like what Geoguessr does, then I don't think that unity is capable of that. You can use Google Maps API in your game like seen in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC51FEF0JeY. That is probably the closest thing you could get in Unity. You can always have your game in a browser that loads Google Maps, a lot of games do that!